# Ruby's nil? function not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using Ruby 1.9.3.

This is what is happening in the console:

```
1.9.3-p392 :028 > p = Product.find(1)
  Product Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `products`.* FROM `products` WHERE `products`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
 => #<Product id: 1, name: "Product 4", image: nil, available: true> 
1.9.3-p392 :029 > p.image
 =>  
1.9.3-p392 :030 > p.image.nil?
 => false
```

When the product is returned, the image is obviously nil, but when I try and get the value (`p.image`) it does not show anything.

Why is the `p.image.nil?` command not returning `true`?

Comment: What happens when using `p.image.equal? nil` (checking premise)? What does `p.image.method(:nil?)` return (checking nonsense override)?

Comment: While @Reza's answer is an effective workaround in this case, it doesn't explain _why_ this is happening. In the future, questions regarding your models should include at least the relevant portions of your model code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `.blank?` it'll return true if the attribute is `nil` or `empty`

Comment: Curious bit is previous line: `#<Product id: 1, name: "Product 4", image: *nil*, available: true>`. Maybe there is magic in image?

Comment: `p.image` should have returned `=> nil`, but it didn't. So I think maybe the code was overwritten such that it returned an empty string or a space (` `).

Comment: When I look at the database itself with phpMyAdmin, the image for that specific product is NULL. I cannot find anything that might make the image not be NULL/nil along the way. In any case, the .blank? method worked, but I can't really understand why.

Comment: Run `p.image.object_id` if it gives you `=> 4` it means it's nil, but if it doesn't maybe somewhere in the code, or php itself, it'll change `image` to an empty string

Comment: To be clear, #blank? is provided by ActiveSupport and is not a native ruby api.

Comment: Ah, good to know, but I use mongoid and it does have that too

Comment: @RezaKazemirad ActiveSupport affects all objects in the system, whether they come from ActiveRecord or Mongoid. It's because you're using Rails.